# Eliminar último carácter de una etiqueta en XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

He llegado a este punto y no logro capturar el contenido de una etiqueta en XML sin el último carácter para poder trabajar con el texto capturado sin el carácter **'_'**

Copiaré un trozo de mi código XML y Java.

En el XML la etiqueta `<span style="color:#ff0000">_</span>` es donde tengo el carácter el cual necesito excluir al capturar **Nombre y Apellidos**

*XML*

```xml
<draw name="Text1" w="29.2864mm" h="5.2331mm">
            <ui>
               <textEdit/>
            </ui>
            <value>
               <exData contentType="text/html">
                  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"><p style="letter-spacing:0in">Nombre y Apellidos<span style="color:#ff0000">_</span></p></body>
               </exData>
            </value>
            <font size="8pt" typeface="BdE Neue Helvetica 45 Light" baselineShift="0pt"/>
            <margin topInset="0.5mm" bottomInset="0.5mm" leftInset="0.5mm" rightInset="0.5mm"/>
            <para spaceAbove="0pt" spaceBelow="0pt" textIndent="0pt" marginLeft="0pt" marginRight="0pt"/>
         </draw>
```

En Java
Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera, pero no logra entrar a la condición IF y cuando imprimo, me sigue imprimiendo los textos con la barra baja.

```java
//Recorro el nodo <draw> del XML
for (int v1 = 0;    v1 < nodeList.getLength();    v1 ++  ){

                Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(v1);
                Node nodo = nodeList.item(v1);
                //Trato con el nodo <body> para capturar el texto
                Node nodeBody = nodeList2.item(v1);


                char textoCampoText = nodeBody.getTextContent().charAt(nodeBody.getTextContent().length() - 1); //System.out.println(textoCampoText);
                System.out.println("textoCampoText: " +textoCampoText);

                if (textoCampoText == '_'){

                    String cadenaNueva = nodeBody.getTextContent().substring(0, nodeBody.getTextContent().length()-1);
                    System.out.println("cadenaNueva:"+cadenaNueva);

                 }else{
                     String cadenaNueva = nodeBody.getTextContent();
                 }
```

Solo me imprime lo que contiene la variable textoCampoText pero valga la redundancia con la barra baja.

Output:

```
textoCampoText:  
Nombre y Apellidos_
textoCampoText:  
Firma:_
textoCampoText:  
Fecha:_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes eliminar o sustituir todas las ocurrencias de un carácter o caracteres con la función  [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), esta cambia un string por otro, dentro de la cadena, en este caso "textCampoText".
Con la siguiente linea de código eliminarías todos los guiones bajos por "" (nada).

```
textCampoText.replaceAll("_", "");
```

Comment: Hola! agrega por favor el por qué debería de agregar esa línea y cual es su función :)

Comment: Gracias @Riaven por la aclaración

Comment: gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente y he simplificado el código , dejare aquí por si alguien le pasa lo mismo. `if(nodeBody!=null){
                    String Textocampo = nodeBody.getTextContent();

                    String cadenaNueva = Textocampo.replaceAll("_", "");

                    System.out.println("CadenaNueva: "+cadenaNueva);
                }`

Comment: @Rebc3sp Hola si es que esta respuesta ha resuelto tu problema por favor márcala como aceptada, con el símbolo check (✓) a la izquierda de la misma